# Print result of js function in href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Can anyone help please;

I have the below;

```
<a href="search-menu/{{data.id}}/{{data.name}}">
```

`data.id` & `data.name` are from `ng-repeat`

I've this function which makes sentence SEO friendly

```
slug = getSlug("Unfriendly Name");
console.log(slug); // Output: unfriendly-name
```

How can I use this in my `href`?

Something like;

`<a href="search-menu/{{data.id}}/javascript:getSlug({{data.name}})">`??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of href use ng-href

```
<a ng-href="search-menu/{{data.id}}/getSlug(data.name)">
```

you can also make a function in your controller that will return the whole string.

```
<a ng-href="your wholeStringFunction(data.id, data.name)">
```